# How To Identify A StripLine Within The StripLines Collection (Axis) (Serialization)?

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I am writing a sort of MsCharts designer.
- Design Chart, ChartAreas, Series,...
- The object is saved via the standard System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart.ChartSerializer

I want the user to be able to add multiple Striplines to the Axis's.
I am attempting to identify a StripLine within the StripLines Collection of an Axis.

The Name property of a StripLine is read only (get, no set).
I see no way to actually set the Name property.
I do not understand how this is useful?

I was going to use the Tag property of the StripLine but alas the Tag property is not serialized.
Note:

If I edit the serialized chart and add Tag="AStripLine" to a  element and then load it via Chart.ChartSerializer The Tag= value is in fact there.

If I save / serialize the chart via Chart.ChartSerializer Tag is not saved.

Any help / ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you open to a Reflection based solution and the associated brittleness it imparts on your code?

Comment: I shared a solution based on type description mechanism which makes the `Tag` property visible and editable in property grid and also serializes and deserializes it well. The reason which I decided to use this solution is to allow user to add strip lines using property grid collection editor and see/change the tag property if needed. You can hide the property, it doesn't have any impact on its serialization. Also you can change the type of property to a complex type which is convertible to/from string. I even tried a structure supporting `ExpandableObjectConverter` for better user experience.

Answer (score 1):

`Tag` property is of type of `object` and it's decorated with an internal attribute telling the serializer to not serialize `Tag` property. So the behavior is expected.

But since the serializer relies on `TypeDescriptor`, you can create a new `TypeDescriptor` for `StripLine` class describe `Tag` property in a different way, for example:

- Make it browsable in property grid
- Make it editable in property grid
- Make it serializable for chart serializer

So it serializes and deserializes it correctly with this format, for example:

```
<StripLine Text="text1" Tag="1" />
```

Also shows it in property grid at run-time:

[image]

You need to create the following classes:

- `StripLineTypeDescriptionProvider`: Helps to register a new type descriptor for `StripLine`
- `StripLineTypeDescriptor`: Describes the properties of the type and allows you to change `Tag` property behavior. In this class we override `GetProperties` and replace the `Tag` property with a modified property descriptor which tells the serializer to serialize `Tag` and also tells the property grid to show it and make it editable.
- `MyPropertyDescriptor`: Helps us to specify the new type of `Tag` property. You can decide to set it as string, int or even a complex type. It's enough the type be convertible to and from string.

Then it's enough to register the type descriptor for `StripLine` in constructor or load event of the form:

```
var provider = new StripLineTypeDescriptionProvider();
TypeDescriptor.AddProvider(provider, typeof(StripLine));
```

**Implementations**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
```

```
public class StripLineTypeDescriptionProvider : TypeDescriptionProvider
{
    public StripLineTypeDescriptionProvider()
       : base(TypeDescriptor.GetProvider(typeof(object))) { }

    public override ICustomTypeDescriptor GetTypeDescriptor(Type objectType, object instance)
    {
        ICustomTypeDescriptor baseDescriptor = base.GetTypeDescriptor(objectType, instance);
        return new StripLineTypeDescriptor(baseDescriptor);
    }
}
```

```
public class StripLineTypeDescriptor : CustomTypeDescriptor
{
    ICustomTypeDescriptor original;
    public StripLineTypeDescriptor(ICustomTypeDescriptor originalDescriptor)
        : base(originalDescriptor)
    {
        original = originalDescriptor;
    }
    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties()
    {
        return this.GetProperties(new Attribute[] { });
    }
    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        var properties = base.GetProperties(attributes).Cast<PropertyDescriptor>().ToList();
        var tag = properties.Where(x => x.Name == "Tag").FirstOrDefault();
        var tagAttributes = tag.Attributes.Cast<Attribute>()
            .Where(x => x.GetType() != typeof(BrowsableAttribute)).ToList();
        var serializationAttribute = tagAttributes.Single(
            x => x.GetType().FullName == "System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Utilities.SerializationVisibilityAttribute");
        var visibility = serializationAttribute.GetType().GetField("_visibility",
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
             System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
        visibility.SetValue(serializationAttribute, Enum.Parse(visibility.FieldType, "Attribute"));
        tagAttributes.Add(new BrowsableAttribute(true));
        var newTag = new MyPropertyDescriptor(tag, tagAttributes.ToArray());
        properties.Remove(tag);
        properties.Add(newTag);
        return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(properties.ToArray());
    }
}
```

```
public class MyPropertyDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
{
    PropertyDescriptor o;
    public MyPropertyDescriptor(PropertyDescriptor originalProperty,
        Attribute[] attributes) : base(originalProperty)
    {
        o = originalProperty;
        AttributeArray = attributes;
    }
    public override bool CanResetValue(object component)
    { return o.CanResetValue(component); }
    public override object GetValue(object component) => o.GetValue(component);
    public override void ResetValue(object component) { o.ResetValue(component); }
    public override void SetValue(object component, object value) { o.SetValue(component, value); }
    public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component) => true;
    public override AttributeCollection Attributes => new AttributeCollection(AttributeArray);
    public override Type ComponentType => o.ComponentType;
    public override bool IsReadOnly => false;
    public override Type PropertyType => typeof(string);
}
```

**References**

Here are source code for classes which will help you to learn how the chart serialization works:

- [ChartElement](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization/Common/General/BaseClasses.cs,a6a748cfc0a32ed7)
- [ChartSerializer](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization/Common/General/ChartSerializer.cs,f0efe37d999127f2)
- [SerializerBase](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization/Common/Utilities/XmlSerializer.cs,d18e1c430f28a9cc)
- [XmlFormatSerializer](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization/Common/Utilities/XmlSerializer.cs,a0f38410c34597bd)

Answer (score 0):

This is truely a weird finding!

At first I thought that maybe the `Names` would be autogenerated in a useful way, say `StripLine1`, `StripLine2` etc.

But they all get `StripLine` as their `Name`.

So it will be useless for your purpose of identifiying them.

There is however the `Tag` property that comes to the rescue; it easy to e.g. set to a unique string..:

```
StripLine sl = new StripLine()
    { Text = "LW" , StripWidth = 2, ForeColor = Color.Teal, Tag = "Low-Water"};
```

To make it unique for an axis `AxisY` could use this:

```
StripLine sl = new StripLine()
    { Text = "LW" , StripWidth = 2, ForeColor = Color.Teal, 
      Tag = "Low-Water" + chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.StripLines.Count };
```

As `Tag` is of type `object` you could create a class to hold more info, like a shortname and a description..

**Update**: I just noticed that you know about `Tags` and how they are not serialized. You could however use this workaround:

- Before Serializing you loop over all `StripLines` and change the `Text` to : oldText + separator + Tag string.
- After de-serializing you do the reverse.

As separator you could use the tab (\t) or other characters (or strings) you don't expect in the texts.. (The vertical tab, my original idea is not an allowed xml entity..)

Here is a function to prepare the `Text` and to reconstruct the `Tags`:

```
void StripLineTagger(Chart chart, bool beforeSer)
{
    char sep = '\t';

    var axes = new List<Axis> { chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX, chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX2,
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY, chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2};

    foreach (var ax in axes)
        foreach (var sl in ax.StripLines)
        {
            if (beforeSer) sl.Text = sl.Text + sep + sl.Tag.ToString();
            else
            {
                var p = sl.Text.Split(sep);
                sl.Text = p[0];
                sl.Tag = p[1];
            }
    }
}
```

This is untested and lacks all checks..!

**Update 2:**

You could add a subclass of your own to replace the regular `StripLines`:

```
class MyStripLine : StripLine
{
    new public string Name { get; set;  }  // looks fine butwon't get serialized
    public string ID{ get; set;  }         // gets serialized

    //..

    public MyStripLine()
    {

    }
}
```

They can be added to the StripLines collections and work as expected. Unfortunately the `Name` property only looks good but doesn't get written out.. an while using another property (`ID`) is simple I can't get de-serialization to work.

Comment: Thanks but I need to serialize the chart in order to persist the design. As stated The Tag property is not serialized within the <StripLines> element via Chart.ChartSerializer().

Comment: Thanks. Yes I am aware of such an approach. My posting here is to see if anyone knows a way around my issue (the less code the better). I understand a Tag is an object, but I am surprised loading the Serialized XML (in which I have manually added the Tag="") will read the Tag attribute (it works flawlessly) but will not write the Tag attribute when saving.

Comment: Since you are using the built-in serializer, I don't know if you can mark Tag as serializable or add a serializableTag, which is what I do when save classes of my own.. Have a look at the example function. It will add just one line  to the save and load calls each..

Comment: I am impressed with your effort to get me to bye into your solution. It is a good solution. But, I also allow the user to edit / create the Text of a Stripline. They can access it from a properties type interface along with clicking on the Stripline (editing in two different places). So in the end it is not one line of code. If no one else can come up with  better solution be assured I will select your answer as the Solution. Thanks.

Comment: I did understand that you are writing a chart editor. (I always wanted to do that :-) so of course the sl.Text must be dynamic. But that won't be a problem; just add the lines before saving and after loading. - I wish I could come up with a more direct solution, but Name being read-only and distinctly non-unique I really can't find anyhing one can be sure (i.e. can control) to be unique.

Comment: Hm, I just came up with a different idea, see my update 2 ! Now the new Name property is read/write. - But the Serializer acts up and tells me that : System.Xml.XmlException: "The '+'-characterZeichen, hex 0x2B, must not be in a Name. Hmm??

Comment: Maybe UTF-16. A Tab 0x0009 is really not a printable character (it is white space). I am not sure how the Serialize will handle white space in XML. Change It To and alpha and see what happens? Thanks for being a dog with a bone!

Comment: No, it was due to the uncomplete class. After adding a constructor to the MyStripLine class it works.fine but ignores the Name property.. Of course an ID or other name string could be used instead. The real question is: Is it preferrable to do with a Tag or with a class of our own?

Comment: I do not have enough points to move this to a chat. Can you move it to a chat?

Comment: I just tested Loading the xml but found that it can't load the subclass..

Comment: When going for the Tag workaround you can add a labelled TextBox and load the Tag there when loading the PropertyGrid  and write back the content (Name) to the Tag in the TextChanged event.. - But when going for a StripLine subclass the added ID field will show up in the ProperyGrid.but I can't get de-serialization to work - . Btw: You were right: \v is not allowed. You may go for \t, \r or \n..

Comment: @TaW I tried your solution which you shared in update 2. It serializes the object as `<MyStripLine ID="100" />` then when trying to load,  `chart1.Serializer.Load` throws an exception. Am I missing something? I probably can make it working, but not easier than using type descriptor solution which I shared.

Comment: Exactly what I wrote in my last comment :-( _I can't get de-serialization to work_ - Your answer is very interesting (+1) but I would also be curious if/how you would fix the deserialization issue I ran into..

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've already tried a few things without any success. I'll share with you if I found anything useful.